# error when creating S3 replication configuration for bucket - Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-iam, infrastructure-as-code

Im trying to create s3 buckets using terraform with replication configuration based on https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_replication_configuration#using-replication-configuration

I tried the actual code, changed the names to my desired bucket names and run terraform init, plan, and apply but i ended up having this error.

```
│ Error: error creating S3 replication configuration for bucket (nameofmybucket): AccessDenied: Access Denied
│       status code: 403, request id: xxx, host id: xxx
│
│   with aws_s3_bucket_replication_configuration.replication,
│   on main.tf line 123, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_replication_configuration" "replication":
│  123: resource "aws_s3_bucket_replication_configuration" "replication" {
│
```

the only change i did apart from the bucket name is to add `delete_marker_replication{...}` due to error when it is enabled by default.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_replication_configuration" "replication" {
  provider = aws.central
  # Must have bucket versioning enabled first
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_versioning.source]

  role   = aws_iam_role.replication.arn
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.source.id

  rule {
    id = "Replication V2 Rule"
    filter {}
    status = "Enabled"
    destination {
      bucket        = aws_s3_bucket.destination.arn
      storage_class = "STANDARD"
    }
    delete_marker_replication {
      status = "Disabled"
    }
  }
}
```

Anyone here encountered this issue before? and how were you able to resolved it?
i already change my service account access to full access thinking that it might be caused by my service account access rights.

Comment: Maybe your bucket name is not unique. Did you try with different name?

Comment: yup i tried replacing it several times while changing few configurations like status etc. cant find anything related to my issue in terraform docs - really weird

Comment: Is the rule name unique? Or may the account be under any SCP?

Comment: @ErikAsplund you mean `id = "Replication V2 Rule"`? yup its unique i also tried changing the value of the id. to answer if the account is under SCP im not sure yet. do you know a faster way to check it?

Comment: Could it be related to the destination bucket? In other words, are there any bucket policies that could prevent it from replicating?

Comment: @PANDAMAN I don't think where is a way to see if an account is affected by an SCP in the account it self, you need access to the Organization account. But if your account isnt under an Organization it wont be affected by an SCP. You can see if the account is under an Organization here:
https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/organizations/v2/home/dashboard

Comment: @ErikAsplund it seems that your right. i tested several inline policies but nothing works until i added full access from organization account. its turns out not a terraform / script issue but a missing permission that i missed to include that AdministratorAccess provides

Comment: Good it worked out for you! Do you want me to add it as an answer to your question?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may have the incorrect provider. Is that provider pointing towards your replication account? If so, it needs to be pointing towards the source account/default role.

I was getting this same error until I realized I may have been incorrectly setting the provider

Comment: I was using the wrong provider for a cross-account replication config. This was my exact issue!

Answer (score 0):

For my case it was missing IAM permissions "iam:PassRole" as is mentioned in the AWS documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-replication.html